# set rows with fact_wrap with ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have want to make a facet_wrap, but there are too many columns to fit nicely on a page,
dummy example:

```
# Creating some dummy data
set.seed(123)
mydata <- data.frame(
  x = rnorm(120),
  y = rnorm(120),
  group1 = rep(c("A", "B", "C","D", "E", "F"), each = 40),
  group2 = rep(c("G", "H"), each = 40)
)

# Creating the plot with facet grid
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(mydata, aes(x = x, y = y)) +
  geom_point() +
  facet_grid(group2 ~ group1)
```

[image]

Is there any way make this so it is sort of more square like this with 2 rows for G and H instead of one:

[image]

Comment: this should be possible with the `ggh4x` package, and in particular its `facet_manual`

Answer (score 1):

One option could be to use `patchwork` to combine faceted graphs for each group and set the secondary y-axis title to be the group title to denote these:

```r
set.seed(123)
mydata <- data.frame(
  x = rnorm(120),
  y = rnorm(120),
  group1 = rep(rep(c("A", "B", "C","D", "E", "F"), each = 40), times = 2),
  group2 = rep(c("G", "H"), each = 240)
)

# Creating the plot with facet grid
library(tidyverse)
library(patchwork)

p1 <- mydata |> 
  filter(group2 == "G") |> 
  ggplot(aes(x = x, y = y)) +
  geom_point() +
  scale_y_continuous(sec.axis = sec_axis(name = "Group G", trans = ~., breaks = NULL)) +
  theme(axis.title.y.left = element_text(size = 12)) +
  facet_wrap(~ group1, nrow = 2)

p2 <- mydata |> 
  filter(group2 == "H") |> 
  ggplot(aes(x = x, y = y)) +
  geom_point() +
  scale_y_continuous(sec.axis = sec_axis(name = "Group H", trans = ~., breaks = NULL)) +
  theme(axis.title.y.left = element_text(size = 12)) +
  facet_wrap(~ group1, nrow = 2)

p1 / p2
```

[image]

Comment: nice. Worth to note that you have also slightly modified the data.

Comment: yes slightly modified to not drop empty panels. I'd be in favour of a `ggh4x` solution also as slightly less hacky, but don't know the package well!